# removed fstab mount, all that is left is an "a" file

Tags: fstab

I have removed a mount point on fstab. Since restarting i can still see the location it was mounted to but all that is in there is a file named "a".

What is this file?
[image]

Comment: You must have mistyped a command, resulting in an empty file. Nothing to worry about. Delete it.

Comment: When a disk (partition) gets mounted, it hides any files that exists in the "mount pionts" (dir)

Comment: was this a mount point you created to mount a drive or one created by the system during the installation process?